# Can LibreOffice render images in HTML without the "file:///" path prefix?

Tags: images, html, libreoffice

I have a bunch of HTML docs with images stored a local JPEG files specified as follows:

```
<img src="c:/data/image.jpg" alt="FOO">
```

When I load these HTML into LibreOffice, the images are not rendered. The only way to fix this that I found is to change the paths to

```
<img src="file:///c:/data/image.jpg" alt="FOO">
```

Is there a way to reconfigure LibreOffice so that it renders the images with the original path not requiring the `file:///` prefix? Word can do, so I am hoping LO can too.